gcloud SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED Error on SSH
I have installed google-cloud-sdk using binary on my MacBook M1. I just copied the package from official GCP site and add the path export PATH="/Users/ZSHAREE/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH" to my .zprofile.
Everything works fine and I can execute different gcloud commands e.g.:
gcloud auth login
gcloud init
gcloud config configurations list

But when I try to do port-forwarding using SSH command given below:
gcloud compute ssh mbadas-dev-bastionhost \
    --tunnel-through-iap \
    --project=mb-adas-mlops-d-0031 \
    --zone=europe-west4-a

then I get the SSL certification error, as given below:
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.compute.iap_tunnel_websocket.ConnectionCreationError: Error while connecting [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)].
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535

Any idea that why I am getting the SSL error on using gcloud for port-forwarding using SSH

IAP is why - Google port-forwards through HTTPS so that it can reuse your gcloud tokens. Do you use a proxy?

No ... I am not using any proxy.

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

Hi @ZeeshanShareef If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Try below steps to resolve the error :

An outdated version of the gcloud SDK may have outdated certificate information, leading to compatibility problems. So update to the latest version of the gcloud SDK installed. Refer to the GCP document for more details.

As a workaround try run below command to disable ssl verification :
gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True .

Check MacOS Antivirus, Firewall rules to allow incoming SSH traffic on the port you're trying to forward and also check necessary IAM permissions are there to access the instance and the IAP service.


Also follow the official GCP Troubleshoot SSL certificates and Medium Blog by Dan Devis to fix this SSL error on using gcloud.
Note : Sometimes due to incorrect system time and date can also lead to certificate validation errors. synchronize date and time on both your local machine and the server.
